# Send array of objects via GET request with Angular's $http to Java Spring

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, http-get

I have a javascript variable which is an array of MyObjects. I can display this variable to the view with the following code:

```
        <tr ng-repeat="user in lala.users">
            <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
        </tr>
```

Now I am trying to send this array to the server. I am trying something like:

```
    lala.send = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "http://localhost:8080/server/" + lala.users
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                lala.users = response.data
            }
        });
    };
```

How can I pass this array to a list on the server side? Till now I have something like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/server/{users}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<MyObjects>> transform(@PathVariable("users") String[] users) {
        List<MyObjects> results2 = new ArrayList<>();

        //pass array to a list??

        return new ResponseEntity<>(results2, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: If you want to send it with a get request, you have to manually split them up or encoded them in some way. The easiest solution though is to wrap the array in a JSON object and post that object to the server.

Comment: are you using spring boot?

Comment: Yes, it is spring boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform your string and use a delimiter, then parse it on your server side. You can also use **HttpPost** instead of **HttpGet** request so you can send JSON String and it is easier to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ranielle's answer I proceeded with HttpPost.

Here is the code:

```
lala.send = function() {
            $http.post("http://localhost:8080/server", lala.users ) 
            .then(function successCallback(response) {
                if (response.status == 200) {
                   lala.users = response.data
                }
            });
        };
```

And the Spring side

```
@RequestMapping(value = "server", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<MyObjects> sort( @RequestBody List<MyObjects> query) {
        List<MyObjects> results2 = new ArrayList<>();

        for(MyObjects a : query) {
                System.out.println(a.getFirstName());
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(results2, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```