# Angular - $http.post send data as json

Tags: angularjs, json, http-post

I have a javascript variable which is an array of MyObjects. I can display this variable to the view with the following code:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="user in lala.users">
        <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
    </tr>
```

How can I send this to a server as **json** using **post**?

Comment: Why are you changing my tag from angular to angularjs?

Comment: $http.post is AngularJS syntax

Comment: Thanks mate! My bad.

Comment: @CapBaracudas have you tried: `$http.post("http://localhost:8080/server/", {"data":lala.users})` ?

Comment: I am not sure why but it seems that I can just do $http.post('Url', lala.users) . Thanks though cause your answers works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to inject $http to you controller or Server or factory.

```
      $http.post('/saveusers', users).then(function(data) {
        $scope.message = data;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a person object:

```
let postMessage = JSON.stringify({
  'person': {
    'firstName': this.user.firstName,
    'lastName': this.user.lastName
  }
});
```

then you can use the postMessage to send it with the:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this.http.post('URL', postMessage, options)
```

Comment: you can make more assumptions from his [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633039/send-array-of-objects-via-get-request-with-angulars-http-to-java-spring)